# Python init class with either instance of a class or kwargs

Tags: python

I have two classes (`A` and `B`), where `A` is a parameter to init `B`. When initializing `B`, I would like to be able to *either* pass in an instance of `A` or the kwargs to initialize an instance.

Is there a better way to do this than the below?

```py
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

class B(object):
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a if isinstance(a, A) else A(**a)

a = A(x=1, y=2)
(a.x, a.y) # (1, 2)

b = B(a)
(b.a.x, b.a.y) # (1, 2)

b = B(dict(x=3, y=4))
(b.a.x, b.a.y) # (3, 4)
```

I was thinking that maybe some `@classmethod` constructor on `A` might be a better approach.

**Update:**

I think that a `@classmethod` is probably the best way to do the above (and there may be cases where it is in fact necessary), but I decided to avoid this pattern and instead require an instance of `A` to be passed.

At first I was hesitant because init `A` had side effects (it started a data connection). I changed this pattern so that the data connection would start by a separate method and hence initializing instances of `A` to pass to `B` did not seem as bad

Comment: Why construct an instance of `A` inside `B` anyway? You could force the caller to construct `A` themselves and make `B` only accept instances of `A`. This will also decouple `A` and `B`: currently some instantiations of `B` depend on the kind of arguments `A`'s constructor takes, so once you change `A`'s interface, suddenly instantiations of _`B`_ will break.

Comment: Without getting too into the weeds of the setup (this is a minimum example), the reasoning behind initializing `A` inside `B` is that I have a separate generic factory process for `B` which takes in a dict (i.e. kwargs). Rather than specify an instance of `A` in that dict I would just specify the params that initialize A as well

Comment: I was thinking I could edit `B` to accept `a` _and_ `x,y` and have logic that is something like... if `a` is given, `self.a = a` otherwise if `x,y` given `self.a = A(x,y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take two approaches:

1. Use the line `a if isinstance(a, A) else A(**a)` or equivalent in some form or another.
2. Make the user pass in `A` instead of supporting multiple types of inputs.

**I think the second approach is more pythonic.**

Given that, you can factor out the test into a separate method. A `classmethod` is as good a solution as any for this:

```
class A:
    ...
    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, args):
        if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], cls):
            return args[0]
        return cls(*args)

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = A.get_instance(a)
```